# Include Javascript into an XML file?

Tags: javascript, xml, jira

I am developing an atlassian Jira plugin which includes an XML file and some javascript code. Here is the xml part when I want to include a Javascript variable but I don't know how. To be more precise, I want the link part to be dynamically changed by a Javascript variable.

```
<web-item name="Security Incident" i18n-name-key="security-incident.name" key="security-incident" section="system.top.navigation.bar" weight="1000">
<description key="security-incident.description">The Security Incident Plugin</description>
<label key="security-incident.label"></label>
<link linkId="security-incident-link">https://jira.seavus.com/jira/servicedesk/customer/portal/6</link>
```